# Invalid utf8 detected in string in CSV

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a CSV file that is being ingested into Snowflake daily. All of a sudden, Snowflake decided to complain about an invalid utf8 character. (which is þ)
I checked in the target table, and it was ingested many times before with no issues. Did something change on Snowflake side? Is there a better way to solve this other than using `REPLACE_INVALID_CHARACTERS = TRUE` which will convert the character into a � ?

Comment: It could be an input side problem. Was the file bytes `0xC3 0xBE` thus utf-8 encoding, or was the file of some other encoding (utf16) method, thus not utf8?

Comment: What's the method of ingestion, do you know since which version you started facing the issue? What's the exact error message?

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim good hint! All previous CSV files were utf-8 encoded except the one that failed it has latin1. I should verify with the source system.